# Can a Visual C++ program be compiled and run on Mac OS X or Linux?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-c++, osx-snow-leopard

… and if so, how?

Specifically, I'd like to compile and run [wavdiff](http://code.google.com/p/ac3filter/source/browse/wavdiff.cpp?repo=tools#) on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8. As far as I can tell (which isn't very far, since I'm a total novice at C++), this was created with MS Visual C++ or similar.

I'd be most grateful for answers that address the general case of compiling Visual C++ programs on Mac OS X or Linux, and that also address the specific challenge above.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Visual C++ program", as there is no such programming language as Visual C++.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Sorry vlad but that's the most useless condescending comment ever. The guy admints he's a novice at c++ - you don't need to highlight at easy target with a comment like that. It's like stomping on goldfish. It's not nice.

Comment: Well technically.... it kinda has enough vendor-specific changes to make it almost a language on its own.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko That was entirely useless as well as rude.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, by "Visual C++ program", I meant a program created using MS Visual C++. I didn't mean a program written in a programming language called Visual C++. I think this is fairly clear from my question, but I'm sorry if it wasn't clear to you. Thank you to the other commenters above who understood my intended meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ language is portable. In theory, C++ source code can be compiled to run on any platform.

However, there are a few caveats to be aware of:

- behavior might be different on different platforms. The C++ standard leaves many things implementation-defined, which means that it's up to the individual platform and compiler how it should behave. For example, the size of common data types can (and will) vary across different platforms. A `long` is typically 64 bits wide on 64-bit Linux, but only 32-bit on 64-bit Windows. A `wchar_t` is 16 bits wide on Windows, but typically 32 bits on Linux. So if your code makes assumptions about implementation-defined behavior, it might not be portable (a classic example is code which assumes that a pointer can be stored into an `int` or `unsigned int`. That works great on a 32-bit machine, but on 64-bit, you end up trying to store 64 bits of data into a 32 bit wide object.
- even if your code is portable, your dependencies may not be. The most obvious example is of course the OS APIs. Code which uses the Win32 API won't compile on platforms where it's not available (anywhere other than Windows). Code which relies on POSIX APIs won't compile if that's not available (Windows supports some POSIX APIs, but far from all).
- C++ can mean a lot of different things. There's the ISO standardized language, which is portable, and then there's the dialect understood by individual compilers. Visual C++, GCC, and any other major C++ compiler, allow a set of language extensions which aren't part of the standard, and may not be allowed on a different compiler. If your code relies on those, it may not compile using other compilers. (For example, Visual C++ allows a non-const reference to bind to a temporary, which isn't strictly speaking allowed, and other compilers will reject it. GCC by default allows dynamically sized arrays allocated on the stack, which, again, is a non-standard extension, and which other compilers will reject.)

So it depends on the code, really. Clean, high-quality code tends to be portable with little trouble. Except of course for the parts that rely directly on OS services, which will have to be rewritten for a different OS (or where a cross-platform wrapper/library may be available which can be used to do the same thing in a portable manner)

Comment: Thank you for making these useful points. How best might a C++ novice go about identifying whether a given piece of C++ source code is portable? Is there a checklist I might be able to use, for instance, or a "portability-checker" program I could run on the source code?

Comment: Nope, your best bet is probably just to try and compile it with different compilers on different OS'es. :) And compile with as many warnings as possible, in the strictest mode possible (for GCC, `-ansi`, `-pedantic` and `-std=c++98`/`-std=c++0x` are very useful, for example)

Answer (score 3):

This program can not be easily ported (recompiled without source changes). At least not without changes to the source. It holds dependencies to Windows libraries and is tied to Windows API in certain parts.

The problem is not that it's coded in VC++, but that it has these dependencies. A program that is coded such that it has no platform-dependencies can be easily ported in a lot of cases by just recompiling on the target platform or with a switch to target a different platform.

Answer (score 2):

Based just on this source file, it looks as if the code itself might be reasonably portable C++. The question is whether it (or any of the classes it uses) makes use of Windows APIs that won't exist on those other platforms. The bet you can do is ask the authors what they think, or just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Before posting my question, I downloaded the ZIP containing wavdiff.cpp and ran "c++ wavdiff.cpp" in a Terminal window. This resulted in errors including "source/wav_source.h: No such file or directory" and "‘printf’ was not declared in this scope". When you said, "give it a try", was that the sort of thing you had in mind, or should I have done things differently?

Comment: It's reasonably portable, I got it to nearly compile after about 5 minutes. c++ -I ../valib/valib wavdiff.cpp $(ls ../valib/valib/*.cpp | grep -v vtime.cpp) $(ls ../valib/valib/{filters,dsp,fir,parsers,sink,source}/*.cpp | grep -v dsound | grep -v dshow) leaves a few linking errors, but probably another 30 minutes or so will give a better result

Comment: @Petesh thank you for having a go with wavdiff.cpp. Can I ask what platform you were using? On my OS X 10.6.8 system, the command you gave produced no new files at all, so I guess it didn't result in a successful compile.

Comment: It fails the link at the end. Because it's a monolithic compile line (i.e. a bunch of .cpp files), it does not keep the intermediate files. When the c++ command completes, if you end up with a file called a.out, then it compiled successfully - the a.out file is the wavdiff binary. If you use c++ -o wavdiff, it would generate a file called wavdiff.

Comment: I didn't get a file called a.out: literally no new files at all were created. But thanks anyway for getting me a bit closer :)